# Como criar quebra de linha automático com UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Estou criando um app para postagem de conteúdo católico, mas estou com um problema, eu tenho uma `UIViewController` com um titulo, uma imagem do post e abaixo da imagem o conteúdo, dependendo se o usuário postar um contendo muito extenso a View esconde parte do conteúdo devido o tamanho da view, coloquei um `UIScrollView`, mas surgiu uma duvida de como fazer com que o Label crie quebras de linhas automático e como aumentar a dimensão da `ScrollView`.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar em relação a isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você definir a propriedade _Lines_ da label para 0 dentro do storyboard ela assume automaticamente a quantidade de linhas necessárias para seu texto.

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa é usar o textView, ele já tem um scroll próprio. Para textos com várias linhas ele é mais indicado do que uma label.
Se desejar usar UILabel com scrollView, a respeito da quebra de linhas, você também pode fazer isso pelo storyboard. Você pode aumentar o número de linhas pelo "Lines", e para quebrar a linha, mude o "Line break".

[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 2):

Scroll é só voce add constrain para ele, ai ele vai se adaptar a todos os tamanhos! era isso?

Sobre a quebra de linha, se voce olhar nas propriedades, da pra voce ver quantas linhas quer que tenha o UILabel e tambem coloque contrains nele, voce tem certeza que quer usar uma UILabel para conteudo?

```
label.numberOfLines = 3;
```